# What is different between forms Authentication timeout vs session timeout in Asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config

What is different between session timeout and forms timeout property

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Administrator/Default.aspx" loginUrl="login" timeout="180" >
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="300">
    </sessionState>
```

how differ **<forms> timeout vs <sessionstate> timeout** properties in web.config file.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forms timeout is the inactivity timeout for forms authentication (or absolute timeout if you're not using sliding expiration).

Sessionstate timeout is the inactivity timeout for the user's session data - e.g. any session data you store for that user.

Comment: The forms timeout is specifically the cookie timeout before reauthentication is required by the user. This works different under different ASP versions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx

Comment: Hello @Bernie, Some time my application shows the redirection loop error.. what's the issue.?

Comment: @AbhishekBhalani this is sometimes because your login page requires authentication. Perhaps users log in from the home page but when their session times out it redirects them to a page that requires authentication? Generally need more information to help with this, though. Probably needs a separate question...

Comment: @Abhishek Are you successfully authenticating a request? Does the loginUrl login require authentication itself. From the information you have specified you would get redirected to "login" to authenticate then get sent to "Administrator/Default.aspx" after authentication. If the cookie could not be validated at Administrator/Default.aspx and the page requires authentication you would get sent back to login.

Comment: ok @Timbo .. Is it mandatory to setAuthentication cookies when validate user.

Comment: @Abhishek - Depends on your provider, the aspnet membership provider, for instance, will set cookies for you...

Comment: Thanks @Timbo If I set session timeout and forms timeout equals then Will it solved my redirection loop problem?

Comment: Only if you have some very specific logic in your code that would result in this issue. It's more likely that you just need to ensure that the page that gets redirected to, if the authentication times out, doesn't require authentication (it's a guess, but this may be the cause of the loop).